# Meaning of 'rock at'

Tags: verbs, colloquialisms

I am interested in the Drama *So* (alias Gen-X *So*) and came across the following example in a paper, which is a typical example of Drama *So* where 'So' modifies a VP rather than a scalable.adjective or adverb.

(6) I so rock at this.

As far as my little research goes, I could not find a suitable meaning of 'rock at' in the sentence.  I am wondering what the sentence means.  Is 'rock at' here a colloquial use of 'rock'?

Comment: I rock at this = I'm so good at this

Comment: Thanks for an answer.  I thought that it means something like that.

Answer (score 2):

[To rock:](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/you-rock/)

> You rock is a slang phrase of praise or encouragement conveying "***You're awesome (at something)" or "You can do it!"***

Dictionary.com

Comment: Your answer confirms my guess.  Thanks.